# View with <include> tag doesn't updates in RecyclerView android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

View (or even child elements of view) doesn't updates but copies previous item in `RecyclerView`.
I have layout with tree `transaction_status_tree.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/dotConfirmed"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/non_filled_progress_dot"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

            <com.bfl.delivery.customviews.BflTextView
                android:id="@+id/tvConfirmed"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/BflSansTextViewStyle"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/default_material_margin"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/default_material_margin"
                android:text="@string/confirmed"
                tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/progress_line"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

            <com.bfl.delivery.customviews.BflTextView
                android:id="@+id/tvConfirmedInfo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/BflSansTextViewStyle"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/default_material_margin"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/default_material_margin"
                android:text="@string/not_yet"
                android:textSize="@dimen/txt_small_size"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/dotPickedCashier"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/non_filled_progress_dot"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

            <com.bfl.delivery.customviews.BflTextView
                android:id="@+id/tvPickedCashier"
                style="@style/BflSansTextViewStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/default_material_margin"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/default_material_margin"
                android:text="@string/picked_by_cashier"
                tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/progress_line"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

            <com.bfl.delivery.customviews.BflTextView
                android:id="@+id/tvPickedCashierInfo"
                style="@style/BflSansTextViewStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/default_material_margin"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/default_material_margin"
                android:text="@string/not_yet"
                android:textSize="@dimen/txt_small_size"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/trTransferred"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/dotTransferred"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/non_filled_progress_dot"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

            <com.bfl.delivery.customviews.BflTextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTransferred"
                style="@style/BflSansTextViewStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/default_material_margin"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/default_material_margin"
                android:text="@string/transferred"
                tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/trTransferredInfo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/progress_line"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

            <com.bfl.delivery.customviews.BflTextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTransferredInfo"
                style="@style/BflSansTextViewStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/default_material_margin"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/default_material_margin"
                android:text="@string/not_yet"
                android:textSize="@dimen/txt_small_size"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                android:visibility="visible"
                tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/dotSubmitted"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/filled_progress_dot"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

            <com.bfl.delivery.customviews.BflTextView
                android:id="@+id/tvSubmitted"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/BflSansTextViewStyle"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/default_material_margin"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/default_material_margin"
                android:text="@string/submitted"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="8dp"
                android:layout_height="8dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/filled_progress_dot"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

            <com.bfl.delivery.customviews.BflTextView
                android:id="@+id/tvSubmittedInfo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/BflSansTextViewStyle"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/default_material_margin"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/default_material_margin"
                android:text="@string/not_yet"
                android:textSize="@dimen/txt_small_size"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

And I am using it inside my card (item of list) `card_transaction_item.xml` with `<include>` tag:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <!-- View to resolve problem with GONE first item in SwipeRefreshLayout -->
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cvTh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/default_min_divider"
        app:cardCornerRadius="0dp">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                tools:ignore="UselessParent">

                <com.bfl.delivery.customviews.BflTextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvIdTh"
                    style="@style/BflTextViewStyle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/default_material_margin"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/default_material_margin"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_material_margin"
                    android:text="Transaction number"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/txt_card_title_size"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

                <com.bfl.delivery.customviews.BflTextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvCodeTh"
                    style="@style/BflSansTextViewStyle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/default_material_margin"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/default_material_margin"
                    android:text="BFL[xxxxxxxxxx]"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/txt_tiny_size"
                    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/default_material_margin"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/default_material_margin"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_min_divider"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <com.bfl.delivery.customviews.BflTextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvThTimeStamp"
                        style="@style/BflSansTextViewStyle"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/default_material_margin"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/default_material_margin"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="00-00-0000 00:00"
                        tools:ignore="HardcodedText,RtlHardcoded" />

                    <com.bfl.delivery.customviews.BflTextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvThMoney"
                        style="@style/BflSansTextViewStyle"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="2"
                        android:text="$0000"
                        android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
                        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/llExpandTree"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/default_min_divider"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_min_divider"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                    android:paddingTop="20dp">

                    <com.bfl.delivery.customviews.BflTextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvCntStatusTh"
                        style="@style/BflSansSemiBoldTextViewStyle"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/default_material_margin"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:text="Current status"
                        tools:ignore="HardcodedText,InefficientWeight" />

                    <FrameLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="3">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/ivExpandTh"
                            android:layout_width="20dp"
                            android:layout_height="20dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|end"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/default_material_margin"
                            app:srcCompat="@drawable/expand"
                            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
                    </FrameLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

                <include
                    android:id="@+id/statusTreeTh"
                    layout="@layout/transaction_status_tree"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/default_material_margin"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/default_material_margin"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/default_material_margin"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</FrameLayout>
```

So, when I try to refresh list with new items, all views (e.g. all `TextView`) updates successfully except this tree. The tree becomes a copy of tree in previous card (item) in `RecyclerView`.

I have such adapter:

```
public class TransactionsCardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TransactionsCardAdapter.TcaViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<TransactionCardData> cardsData;

    public TransactionsCardAdapter (Context mContext, List<TransactionCardData> cardsData) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.cardsData = cardsData;
    }

    class TcaViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView tvNumber;
        TextView tvCode;
        TextView tvTime;
        TextView tvMoney;
        TextView tvCntStatus;
        ImageView ivExpand;
        CardView cv;
        View tree;
        ImageView ivSubmitted;
        TextView tvSubmitted;
        TextView tvSubmittedDate;
        ImageView ivTransferred;
        TextView tvTransferred;
        TextView tvTransferredDate;
        ImageView ivPickedCashier;
        TextView tvPickedCashier;
        TextView tvPickedCashierDate;
        ImageView ivConfirmed;
        TextView tvConfirmed;
        TextView tvConfirmedDate;
        View expandView;

        View trTransferred;
        View trTransferredInfo;

        TcaViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            tvNumber = v.findViewById(R.id.tvIdTh);
            tvCode = v.findViewById(R.id.tvCodeTh);
            tvTime = v.findViewById(R.id.tvThTimeStamp);
            tvMoney = v.findViewById(R.id.tvThMoney);
            tvCntStatus = v.findViewById(R.id.tvCntStatusTh);
            ivExpand = v.findViewById(R.id.ivExpandTh);
            cv = v.findViewById(R.id.cvTh);
            tree = v.findViewById(R.id.statusTreeTh);
            tvSubmitted = tree.findViewById(R.id.tvSubmitted);
            tvSubmittedDate = tree.findViewById(R.id.tvSubmittedInfo);
            ivSubmitted = tree.findViewById(R.id.dotSubmitted);
            tvTransferred = tree.findViewById(R.id.tvTransferred);
            tvTransferredDate = tree.findViewById(R.id.tvTransferredInfo);
            ivTransferred = tree.findViewById(R.id.dotTransferred);
            ivPickedCashier = tree.findViewById(R.id.dotPickedCashier);
            tvPickedCashier = tree.findViewById(R.id.tvPickedCashier);
            tvPickedCashierDate = tree.findViewById(R.id.tvPickedCashierInfo);
            tvConfirmed = tree.findViewById(R.id.tvConfirmed);
            tvConfirmedDate = tree.findViewById(R.id.tvConfirmedInfo);
            ivConfirmed = tree.findViewById(R.id.dotConfirmed);
            expandView = v.findViewById(R.id.llExpandTree);

            trTransferred = v.findViewById(R.id.trTransferred);
            trTransferredInfo = v.findViewById(R.id.trTransferredInfo);
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public TcaViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.card_transaction_item, parent, false);

        return new TransactionsCardAdapter.TcaViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final TcaViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final TransactionCardData item = cardsData.get(position);
        String formattedId = String.format("%012d", item.getId());
        holder.tvNumber.setText(formattedId);
        holder.tvCode.setText(item.getPackageId());
        String amount = String.valueOf(item.getMoney()) + " " + mContext.getString(R.string.uah);
        holder.tvMoney.setText(amount);

        String cntStatus;

        /* Setting current status in title */
        if (item.getStatusConfirmed() != null) {
            cntStatus = mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.confirmed);
        } else if (item.getStatusPickedCashier() != null) {
            cntStatus = mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.picked_by_cashier);
        } else if (item.getStatusTransferred() != null) {
            cntStatus = mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.transferred);
        } else {
            cntStatus = mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.submitted);
        }

        /* Making dots */
        if (item.getStatusConfirmed() != null) {
            makeConfirmed(item.getStatusConfirmed(), holder);
        }
        if (item.getStatusTransferred() != null) {
            makeTransferred(item.getStatusTransferred(), holder);
        }
        if (item.getStatusPickedCashier() != null) {
            makePickedCashier(item.getStatusPickedCashier(), holder);
        }
        if (item.getStatusSubmitted() != null) {
            makeSubmitted(item.getStatusSubmitted(), holder);
        }

        /* Hiding dot if necessary */
        if (item.getStatusTransferred() == null && item.getStatusPickedCashier() != null) {
            holder.trTransferred.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.trTransferredInfo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        holder.tvCntStatus.setText(cntStatus);
        holder.tvTime.setText(item.getTimeSubmitted());

        holder.expandView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                expandOrCollapse(holder);
            }
        });

    }

    private void makeSubmitted (String dateTime, TcaViewHolder holder) {
        holder.tvSubmittedDate.setText(dateTime);
        holder.tvSubmitted.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        holder.ivSubmitted.setImageDrawable(
                ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.filled_progress_dot)
        );
    }

    private void makePickedCashier (String dateTime, TcaViewHolder holder) {
        holder.tvPickedCashierDate.setText(dateTime);
        holder.tvPickedCashier.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        holder.ivPickedCashier.setImageDrawable(
                ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.filled_progress_dot)
        );
    }

    private void makeTransferred (String dateTime, TcaViewHolder holder) {
        holder.tvTransferredDate.setText(dateTime);
        holder.tvTransferred.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        holder.ivTransferred.setImageDrawable(
                ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.filled_progress_dot)
        );
    }

    private void makeConfirmed (String dateTime, TcaViewHolder holder) {
        holder.tvConfirmedDate.setText(dateTime);
        holder.tvConfirmed.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        holder.ivConfirmed.setImageDrawable(
                ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.filled_progress_dot)
        );
    }

    private void expandOrCollapse (@NonNull final TcaViewHolder holder) {
        long animDuration = 100;
        if (holder.tree.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
            holder.tree.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.ivExpand.animate().rotation(180).setDuration(animDuration);
        } else {
            holder.tree.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.ivExpand.animate().rotation(0).setDuration(animDuration);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return cardsData.size();
    }

    public void updateData (List<TransactionCardData> nData) {
        cardsData.clear();
        cardsData.addAll(nData);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

And I am using `updateData (List<TransactionCardData> nData);` to update my list. 
Please, explain me, what I am doing wrong and why this problem happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RecyclerView` reuses existing views instead of inflating them again. All the fields which are not explicitly updated will hence be copied from some other view. If the child is not being explicitly hidden or updated (like when they are null) old values will be used. So, you will have to add an else case for every child view. Like if some value is null hide it in the else case.

```
 if (item.getStatusConfirmed() != null) {
       makeConfirmed(item.getStatusConfirmed(), holder);
 } else {
        view.setVisibilty(View.GONE);
 }
```